# Table of contents for a specific section of google doc?

Tags: google-docs

A section of a google doc is getting difficult to navigate via any means other than control + f.

Is there a way to add a table of contents at at the start of a specific section of a google doc such that it contains only the contents of that section?

#### Notes

The section starts with a level 1 heading

Subsections are level 2 headings (and sub-sub sections are level 3)

Comment: have you found a way in the meantime? 'cause I'm having the same problem and can't figure it out either...

Comment: @BenoîtWéry nope, no luck unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

The best I found for you is to use "Table of Contents" or "Document Outline"

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/116338?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en 
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6367684

I hope that helps.